# Bash completion: separately show results from different sources

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have followed [this tutorial](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.be/2011/04/writing-your-own-bash-completion.html) to write my bash completion function. It has worked out just fine, but I was wondering if it is possible to separately show completions from different sources.

For example, suppose I have a script that takes a directory as argument and I want to autocomplete the possible directories (listed by `get_dirs`):

```
function _testing_command()
{
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    local prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}

    case "$prev" in
        testing )
            COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$(get_dirs)" -- $cur) )
            ;;
    esac
}
complete -F _testing_command testing
```

This works fine and autocompletes the directories correctly:

```
$ testing <TAB><TAB>
dir1 dir3 dir5
$ testing
```

However, what if I now have a second set of directories (listed by `get_dirs_2`) that I want to include in the autocomplete output. I can do the following:

```
function _testing_command()
{
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    local prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}

    case "$prev" in
        testing )
            COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$(get_dirs) $(get_dirs_2)" -- $cur) )
            ;;
    esac
}
complete -F _testing_command testing
```

Which will give me this output:

```
$ testing <TAB><TAB>
dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4 dir5 dir6
$ testing
```

Technically this is ok, because autocompletion will work on the directories from both sources. But I want the output to somehow signify which directory comes from which location, for example:

```
$ testing <TAB><TAB>
from loc1:
dir1 dir3 dir5
from loc2:
dir2 dir4 dir6
$ testing
```

Do I have any control over the output format? Or is it just not possible to achieve something like this with the complete/compgen functions?

Comment: I don't think it's possible in bash. Zsh can do it, it gives you a lot of control over how completions are displayed.